# Gmail Watch - Pub/Sub - Subscriber stopped receiving push notifications

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I have Pub/Sub enabled in a Google cloud project for my application. I have a topic and a subscription and many users have subscribed to this topic. My server is receiving notifications on Inbox updates for all users except one. We were receiving push notifications for that user till couple of weeks back. I tried to re-subscribe the user for that topic and the call succeeded. Still, my server is not getting push notifications for that user.

Any ideas on why this could happen and how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks and Regards,

Rajesh

Comment: Try [resuming delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#stop), there could be at some point sets the push endpoint URL to an empty string for that particular user cause a messages to accumulate, but was not delivered.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, Thanks for your reply. I have added some more details 
- I  have one topic and one subscription. 
- I have multiple Gmail users (user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com, ...) for whom we will call "Watch" on that topic.
- I have only one subscription and url of which points to my server. 
What is happening is, my server (subscriber) is receiving notifications from all those users except one, ex. user10@gmail.com.
So, I am trying to find ways to see why we are not receiving notifications just for that user.  Do you think it is right and safe to try resuming delivery for my case?

Comment: I have the same issue - pub/sub works fine for all the gmail accounts, but for some reason, one of gmail account isn’t receiving any notifications even though we received confirmation from the watch endpoint... Any idea would be greatly appreciated!